# How do I copy a rectangular array to a standard one in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to extract a one-dimensional array from a rectangular array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232545/whats-the-best-way-to-extract-a-one-dimensional-array-from-a-rectangular-array)

How do I copy a rectangular array to a standard one? Without iterating over each item of course...

```
double[,] rectArray = new double[3,3];
double[] linearArray = new array[9];
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232545/whats-the-best-way-to-extract-a-one-dimensional-array-from-a-rectangular-array

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OfType` or `Cast` method:

```
linearArray = rectArray.OfType<double>().ToArray();
```

Or:

```
linearArray = rectArray.Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Is `OfType` relevant here if just converting a `double[]` to a `double[,]`?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: how you converts from double[] to double[,]?

Comment: `Without iterating over each item of course`

Comment: @L.B: :), you have any approach else?

Comment: @CuongLe Haha, errr, good point! I glanced at the code and thought the `Cast` or `OfType` was irrelevant as both arrays are of the same element-type. But of course you can't call `ToArray()` on an array! Sorry! (I'd already given you +1 anyway...)

Comment: @CuongLe No, But OP wants so. So real answer can be. `No you can't`

Comment: @L.B I think what the OP means is "Without having to iterate over each item *myself*" ie Writing a `for` loop. Even though calling `.OfType()` is still iterating over each item at runtime, I think this answer is what the OP wanted.